# How to print and find youngest in Java parallel arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, system, min

In two parallel arrays, String[] names and int[] ages, every name has a corresponding age and vice versa. Both arrays have the same length, say something like:

```
String[] names = {“Alice”, “Paul”, “Jay”, “Dylan”};
int[] ages = {44, 55, 60, 22};
```

- [ ] Amongst these lists, a method is to be created that will print out the youngest person and their age, something like

```
Dylan is the youngest, at age 22
```

How can I do this?

Comment: iterate over the `int` array, determine the index of the smallest value. From there it should be straigt forward.

Comment: Why do you want to use parallel arrays in the first place? It'd be simpler (and less error prone) to use s single array.